# de.hybris.eventtracking.model.events.AbstractTrackingEvent cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: eclipse, sap-commerce-cloud

I just finished configuring hybris and tried to set up the eclipse project. As per guidelines in the wiki.hybris, I imported all the extensions into the eclipse project. When I try into build and clean, I get more than 3000 compiler errors. One of the errors is the class AbstractTrackingEvent  cannot be resolved to a type. I looked for the particular class in the project folder. I could not find the folder **events** under **de.hybris.eventtracking.model**, which is the cause of the issue.

Am I missing anything while importing the project? There are many such type of issues in my eclipse project. Please let me know how to fix it. I have attached the screenshot for reference.

Note: I am using hybris-commerce-suite 5.7.0.8

[image]

As requested, I am adding the source code.

```
package de.hybris.eventtracking.services.populators;

import de.hybris.eventtracking.model.events.AbstractTrackingEvent;
import de.hybris.eventtracking.services.constants.TrackingEventJsonFields;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.ConversionException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * @author stevo.slavic
 *
 */
public abstract class AbstractTrackingEventGenericPopulator implements
        GenericPopulator<Map<String, Object>, AbstractTrackingEvent>
{
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public AbstractTrackingEventGenericPopulator(final ObjectMapper mapper)
{
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

public ObjectMapper getMapper()
{
    return mapper;
}

protected Map<String, Object> getPageScopedCvar(final Map<String, Object> trackingEventData)
{
    final String cvar = (String) trackingEventData.get(TrackingEventJsonFields.COMMON_CVAR_PAGE.getKey());
    Map<String, Object> customVariablesPageScoped = null;
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cvar))
    {
        try
        {
            customVariablesPageScoped = getMapper().readValue(cvar, Map.class);
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            throw new ConversionException("Error extracting custom page scoped variables from: " + cvar, e);
        }
    }
    return customVariablesPageScoped;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can post your **code**, not a screenshot of your code. Thanks!

Comment: @ramedju. This is not my code. Its been provided by Hybris. Do you think it would help? Its clear that the class is not available in the Hybris product itself. If you really think it will help, I will add the code.

Comment: Yes, it could be great if you can add it. :)

Comment: You don't have to import all extensions under your working environment, simply import the one loaded (lazy or explicitly) by your "localextensions.xml" file.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt, It does not help much as all the projects are interdependent. FYI, the localextensions.xml was empty. I added the contents as per wiki.hybris. Moreover, its mentioned in wiki to copy all the project. Please refer to https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094002#Trail~Preparation_-SettinguptheEclipseWorkspace

Comment: I know all projects are independent that's why they don't all need all extensions...
Did you use the b2c_acc_eventtracking install recipe ?
Did you refresh your workspace after doing a 'ant clean all'
Please refer to this for the event extensions installation https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/hybris+Business+Event+Extensions+-+Technical+Guide#hybrisBusinessEventExtensions-TechnicalGuide-Extensioninstallation

Comment: @Anand again if you don't know what the event extensions are don't add them into your eclipse workspace.
Most likely your not using it in your project so data model classes are not generated into your platform extension, therefore you have compilation issues.

Answer (score 1):

"As per guidelines in the wiki.hybris, I imported all the extensions into the eclipse project."

I don't think the guidelines tell you this. Basically, you want the projects loaded to be the same as those defined in your localextensions.xml and their dependencies. The reason you can't see those is they are not built.

Ensure you have run 'ant build' successfully, refresh the platform project, remove any extensions from your workspace that are not needed for your project, and clean and build in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have provided the project dependencies in each project by checking their individual `extensioninfo.xml` files as shown in below image.

Also sometimes dependent libraries are not imported properly check for those too.

[image: Project Dependencies]

[image: Required Libraries]